# How can I fix my function that is to eliminate from an array a given set of of arguments?

Tags: javascript

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  
  for(var i=1;i<=arguments.length;i++){
   
    arguments[0]=arguments[0].filter(function(element){
      return element!==arguments[i];
    });
  }
  return arguments[0];
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

I am trying to make a function that is supposed to accept some arguments. The first of these arguments is an array of number /or whatever. Then the rest of these arguments are supposed to be the things you want to eliminate in that array.

So for example, destroyer([1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3) should return [1,1]. The order doesn't change, which is what .filter() function supposed to do.

I read the MDN dev. page on arguments object. But I am not familiar yet with object oriented programming in Javascript. But I think for this function, I only need to know how to access the given arguments.

When I did this, my compiler shows two errors messages. 1.Bad assignment 2.Don't make function within a loop. But I don't know how to interpret these messages. Please help me.

Comment: whats wrong with using a filter??

Comment: Why dont you just change the signature of your function

Comment: What is a signature? How should I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is the access of [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in a nested function.

Basically you have this structure

```
function destroyer() {
    // ...
    arguments[0].filter(
        function(element) { // <-----------------------------+
            return element !== arguments[i] //               |
            //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this points to --+
        }
    );
    // ...
}
```

and `arguments[i]` is pointing in the callback for `filter` to the callback.

You could save the value of `arguments[i]` in a variable, which works as a closure for the inner function.

```js
function destroyer() {
    var result = arguments[0],
        testValue, i;

    for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++){
        testValue = arguments[i];                  // save value
        result = result.filter(function(element) {
            return element !== testValue;          // use value
        });
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why do  you have to write out the whole "console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));"? Can you just say "destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);", and when I click RUN, the same thing will appear?

Comment: the function `destroyer` returns an array with the wanted parts. if you omit an assignment or a further processing of the return value, then you see nothing or the result is gone.

Comment: Does testValue, i; mean var testValue, and var i;

Comment: Ok so what your doing is storing argument[i] in  var testValue, which since its declared outiside the function destroyer, is public. I am not too clear on closure. What I understand is in closure, you put a private (that is declared within the outer function) in a inner function, so that private variable can be accessed outside the outer function, by some other function. But all of your variables here are public because they are all declared outside the outer function. So I don't see closure.

Comment: actually only `destroyer` is public. `result`, `testValue` and `i` are private variables of `destroyer`, but in scope of the inner function of the filter callback. that is a closure. private variables of the outer function can be accessed in inner functions, as globals as well. they are in the scope of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use rest parameter, `.indexOf()` to filter elements that are not parameters passed after array parameter

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...not) {
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
    return not.indexOf(el) === -1
  })
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: Is ...not an array?

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong with my .filter() method, and my for loop, and the way I access arguments with arguments[i]?

Comment: Yes `...not` creates an array from remainder of passed parameters. Include `console.log(arguments[i], i)` within `.filter()`  callback; you should be able to view issue.